# how to hide div with jquery when click anywhere except one div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a search input on focus it shows a div with options with following:

```
$("#search").focus(function(){

$("#options").fadeIn("fast");

});
```

I am hiding the div back with this function

```
 $("#search").blur(function(){

$("#options").fadeOut("fast");

});
```

now the problem is even when user clicks at any checkbox in `#option` it hides. How I can stop it hidding when clicking checkboxes?

Comment: i missed ); on both functions pardon me

Comment: This question has already been answered on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element. You have there several possible solutions to address your issue.

Comment: please provide the html markup.

Answer (score 3):

```
 $("#search").blur(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation()
   $("#options").fadeOut("fast");
});
```

Comment: $(this).children('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(){e.stopPropagation();});  // isn't this missing in the blur listener?